# How to return an Observable from a sample data [Angular]

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm learning shallow integration testing in Angular. I've a component `HeroesComponent`. It has got one service injection i.e. `HeroService` and one child component `HeroComponent`. For now I'm trying to mock service injection only. I've some sample data in `HEROES: Hero[]` Here's my spec file:

**heores.component.spec.ts**

```
import { Hero } from "../hero"
import { HeroesComponent } from "./heroes.component";
import { HeroService } from "../hero.service";
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { of } from "rxjs/internal/observable/of";

describe('HeroesComponent', () => {
    let HEROES: Hero[];
    let mockHeroService: HeroService;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeroesComponent>

    beforeEach(() => {
        HEROES = [
            {id: 1, name: 'Ant man', strength: 20},
            {id: 2, name: 'Gohan', strength: 10},
            {id: 3, name: 'Goku', strength: 5}
        ];
        mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHeroes', 'addHero', 'deleteHero']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [HeroesComponent],
            providers: [
                {provide: HeroService, useValue: mockHeroService}
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        })

        fixture=TestBed.createComponent(HeroesComponent);
     })

     it('should set heroes correctly from the service', () => {
        // arrange
        mockHeroService.getHeroes.and.returnValue(of(HEROES));

        // act
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // assert
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.heroes.length).toBe(3);
    })
})
```

But I'm getting this error on console. The problem is with `and` inside my `it()` method:

> ERROR in src/app/heroes/heroes.second.spec.ts(32,39): error TS2339: Property 'and' does not exist > on type '() =>
>   Observable'.

Please point out my mistake. Feel free to ask for more code. Thanks.

PS: Here's the code for `HeroesComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    var strength = 11
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name, strength } as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
      });
  }

  delete(hero: Hero): void {
    this.heroes = this.heroes.filter(h => h !== hero);
    this.heroService.deleteHero(hero).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the pluralsight tutorial that I'm following. For him the code is working without any error: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with mocking, you need to change the syntax of `jasmine.createSpybj` from

```
mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHeroes', 'addHero', 'deleteHero']);
```

to

```
mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj('HeroService', ['getHeroes', 'addHero', 'deleteHero']);
```

And you also need to move             `mockHeroService.getHeroes.and.returnValue(of(HEROES));` before creating a component. Becasue as you creating a component, your constructor and ngOnInit methods will be called. And we are not returning spy data as we are writing this statement after ths.

Also you need to change statement where you are creating a spy:

```
let mockHeroService: jasmine.SpyObj<HeroService>;
```

It will resolve your issue. Please find [documentation here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpyObj%3C/code%3E)

Comment: I just tried this solution. But the same error is still there.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create stackblitz of your code? Also add screenshot of test error

Comment: And I'm following pluralsight tutorial. There `createSpyObj` is accepting only one parameter i.e. the array of required methods.

Comment: Sure. I'll quickly create one.

Comment: There is one more issue with your code, you need to move             mockHeroService.getHeroes.and.returnValue(of(HEROES));
 before creating a component

Comment: Ya, if fixed that part. And I've added a screenshot of the source also. Please check. Till then I'll create a stackblitz.

Comment: I hope it fixed your issue